# Adding a semi-transparent, solid bg color over a jpeg

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an `<img>` tag that I am using as a background image, but I want to have a semi-transparent, solid background color, that still shows the original image, at the same ratio and size, under the background color. Here is some of my code (if you need any more info, please ask. Also, the JS and CSS is all inline, and I use jQuery 3.6.0):

```html
<div class="home-screen">
  <img class="background" alt="Background Image" src="./assets/images/Desktop_Pictures/Catalina-min.jpg" />
</div>
```

```css
div.home-screen {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.home-screen img.background {
  top: -50%;
  margin-left: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```js
var isLaunchpadOpen = false;

function openLaunchpad() {
  if (isLaunchpadOpen == false) {
    $("div.home-screen")
        .css("background-color", "rgb(211, 211, 211)")
        .css("background-origin", "content-box")
        .css("top", 0)
        .css("position", "fixed");

    $("div.home-screen img.background")
        .css("background-blend-mode", "multiply")
        .css("filter", "opacity(50%)");

    isLaunchpadOpen = true;
  } else if (isLaunchpadOpen == true) {
    $("div.home-screen img.background")
        .css("background-color", "none")
        .css("filter", "opacity(100%)")
        .css("background-blend-mode", "normal");

    isLaunchpadOpen = false;
  }
}
```

*Note, this is not all the code, this is only the code that I assume is causing the problem*

Comment: It's not very clear yet I think what you want to do is have unique Classes that are defined in CSS. You can then use `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()`, or `.toggleClass()` to better manage the styling conditionally.

Comment: I think it would be better to add a class and have the stylings in a css sheet rather than adjusting for static css properties. Also element.style.cssText(\`multiline css\`) may be easier to read than chaining jQuery .css methods.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried to use a external stylesheet, and using `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()`, and `toggleClass()`, but could not get it to work. I have not tried using multiline css though...

Comment: You can also send an Object to `.css()` to assign multiple styling at once. See: https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Comment: Thanks for that info, Twisty :)

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch, `element.style.cssText(\`multiline css\`)` does not work (and yes, I put my CSS rules in place of `multiline css`... Am I missing something?

Comment: My apologies @LukeBatema, I wrote it out incorrectly. It would be `element.style.cssText += \`multiline css\`` and element would refer to a dom element, so in this case `let element = $("div.home-screen")[0]`

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you. I guess I learn something new every day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS filter property opacity

```
img {
 filter:opacity(50%);
}
```

in this case i recommend you use the css filter property if you want to know more about the css filter property i recommend you check this examples:

I hope I've helped ;)
[css filter property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)

Comment: Note: you can also add background-color property to the parent div to make your image have a solid color background

Comment: a suggestion, try to always use `MDN` links when pointing to docs related to the web. In your case, here's a link to [`CSS Filter Property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Answer (score 0):

1. Apply `position: relative;` to the wrapper of the image: `.home-screen { psotion: relative; }`
2. Create a pseude-element with `::after` that spans the entire wrapper: `.home-screen::after { display: block; content: ""; position: absolute; inset: 0;`
3. Apply a semi-transparent background-color to the pseudo-element by using a `rgba` color as value.

```css
.home-screen {
  position: relative;
}

.home-screen::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

/* for styling purpose only */
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-screen">
  <img class="background" alt="Background Image" src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This did not do what I wanted to achieve. I am making a solid, semi-transparent background color, over a fully-non-transparent, jpeg, to give off that macOS Launchpad vibe. Thank you for helping, if you can, could you help with this additional detail, as well as look back at the post for updated code? Thanks!